# In flex how should I copy and paste connector connecting two object

Tags: flex4.6

I have dragged objects from Diagram Palette on to the Group container.After that I clicked on connector button and then connect dragged objects by mouse move.Now i want to perform copy and paste.On copying only objects are copying not connector.How can I copy connector with dragged objects.[image]